# How to get response from service on controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to separate the $http.post() call into a ".factory()", But would like to fetch the response which is coming async on the controller. Is there a way of doing that?

Controller:

```
 Login.post($scope.user);
```

Factory:

```
 .factory( 'Login' , function($http,SERVERURL){
    var serverUrl = SERVERURL;

    return {
        'post' : function(user){
            $http.post(serverUrl+'/login', user).
                then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                });    
        }
    };
})
```

There is a .then() but I want that on the controller, so I can behave accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to return the `$http.post` promise, and from success function you could return a data that will return to the consumer of this method. So that you could easily call the factory method from controller & inside `.then` function of that call you could have `success` and `error` function.

**Code**

```
.factory('Login', function($http, SERVERURL) {
     var serverUrl = SERVERURL;
     return {
         'post': function(user) {
             return $http.post(serverUrl + '/login', user).
             then(function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                 return response.data; //return data from here
             }, function(response) {
                 // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                 // or server returns response with an error status.
             });
         }
     };
 })
```

**Controller**

```
Login.post().then(function(data){ //success function
    console.log(data)
}, function(error){ //error function
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: Surely the best answer, especially the part where you return the promise with the modified response (return response,data) so that the service takes the responsibility of preparing the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular's `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) methods return a Promise.

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service.

**Factory**

Your method `post` is not yet returning anything but can quite simply return the Promise which is created by calling `$http.post`:

```
.factory('Login' , function($http, SERVERURL){
    var serverUrl = SERVERURL;

    return {
        'post' : function (user) {
            return $http.post(serverUrl + '/login', user)
//          ^^^^^^
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.data;
                }, function (response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

Then consume the result of the returned Promise by calling `then` on it:

```
Login.post($scope.user).then(function (res) {
    // do something with `res`...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback param.

```
.factory( 'Login' , function($http,SERVERURL){
var serverUrl = SERVERURL;

return {
    'post' : function(user, callback){
        $http.post(serverUrl+'/login', user).
            then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                callback(null, response);
            }, function(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
                callback(response);
            });    
    }
};
})
```

And your controller will become:

```
Login.post($scope.user, function(err, response) {
  if(err) {} //do something if there is an error
  // or deal with the response
});
```

Comment: that explains the downvote. It is just my opinion. OP can choose anything he/she want. I like Node convention everywhere and dont like promises very much.

Comment: People should explain why they down vote otherwise nothing is shared. In your example the `post` method can not be used to resolve on a state change without extra work to convert back to a promise.

Answer (score 0):

To return any response to controller just do:

```
return {
    'post' : function(user){
        return $http.post(serverUrl+'/login', user);
    }
};
```

In your controller you will already call`.then()`